# How to display data in Firebase that is held under a autoID child?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an inventory app in order to keep track of items held in a laboratory. In the laboratory there are different stations which contain different items in them, which as you can see is structured properly in my Firebase database.

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twSgX.png)

[Iphone Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcPk8.png)

My problem comes when I try to delete a particular item out of the tableCell. I am able to remove it from the UI but in firebase the data still remains. I have done coutless reserch but am not able to find anything relating to this particular problem.

**Data Services Class**

```
let DB_BASE = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("laboratory")       //contains the root of our database
let STORAGE_BASE = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

class DataService {

static let ds = DataService()

//DB References
private var _REF_BASE = DB_BASE
private var _REF_STATION = DB_BASE.child("stations")
private var _REF_USERS = DB_BASE.child("users")

//Storage Reference
private var _REF_ITEM_IMAGE = STORAGE_BASE.child("item-pics")

var REF_BASE: FIRDatabaseReference {
    return _REF_BASE
}

var REF_STATION: FIRDatabaseReference {
    return _REF_STATION
}

var REF_USERS: FIRDatabaseReference {
    return _REF_USERS
}

var REF_ITEM_IMAGES: FIRStorageReference {
    return _REF_ITEM_IMAGE
}

//creating a new user into the firebase database

func createFirebaseDBUser(_ uid: String, userData: Dictionary<String, String>) {
    REF_USERS.child(uid).updateChildValues(userData)
}
}
```

**Inventory View Controller**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class InventoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,    UITableViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,   UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var items = [Item]()

private var _station: Station!
private var _item: Item!

var sortIndex = 3

var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
static var imageCache: NSCache<NSString, UIImage> = NSCache()
var imageSelected = false

@IBOutlet weak var itemImageToAdd: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var objectTextInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var brandTextInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var unitTextInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var amountTextInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var addItemView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var currentStationLabel: UILabel!

var station: Station {
    get {
        return _station
    } set {
        _station = newValue
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var currentStationName = station.title

    currentStationLabel.text = currentStationName

    self.items = []

    let currentStation = station.title
    let stationRef = DataService.ds.REF_STATION.child(currentStation!)
    let inventoryRef = stationRef.child("inventory")

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.delegate = self

    inventoryRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.value!)

        self.items = []

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshot {

                print("SNAP: \(snap)")
                if let itemDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    let key = snap.key
                    let item = Item(itemKey: key,
                                    itemData: itemDict)
                    self.items.append(item)
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item = items[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inventoryTableCell", for: indexPath) as? ItemCell {

        if let img = InventoryViewController.imageCache.object(forKey: NSString(string: item.imageURL!)) {

            cell.updateItemUI(item: item, img: img)

        } else {

            cell.updateItemUI(item: item)
        }

        return cell

    } else {

        return ItemCell()
    }
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func postToFirebase(itemImageURL: String) {

    let post: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
        "objectLabel": objectTextInput.text! as AnyObject,
        "brandLabel": brandTextInput.text! as AnyObject,
        "unitLabel": unitTextInput.text! as AnyObject,
        "amountLabel": amountTextInput.text! as AnyObject,

        //post elsewhere as an image for future reference
        "itemImageURL": itemImageURL as AnyObject,

        ]
    let stationText = _station.title
    let stationRef = DataService.ds.REF_STATION.child(stationText!)
    let inventoryRef = stationRef.child("inventory")

    let firebasePost = inventoryRef.childByAutoId()
    firebasePost.setValue(post)

    objectTextInput.text = ""
    brandTextInput.text = ""
    unitTextInput.text = ""
    amountTextInput.text = ""
    imageSelected = false

    tableView.reloadData()
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {

        itemImageToAdd.image = image
        imageSelected = true
    } else {

        print("Please select a valid image")
    }

    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func backToStations(_ sender: Any) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToStations", sender: nil)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: (UITableView!), commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: (NSIndexPath!)) {

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let currentStation = station.title
    let stationRef = DataService.ds.REF_STATION.child(currentStation!)
    let inventoryRef = stationRef.child("inventory")

    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") {action in

        //Insert code to delete values from Firebase
        self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .fade)

    }

    var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { action in

    }

    return [deleteAction, editAction]
}  
}
```

My thought process is upon delete to call self_items.key reffering to the current key of the particular tableCell row. From there I would use the current key whick would be the autoID and remove the value that way. Unfortunatly though that crashes the program with a fatal nil error.

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete a specific child node in Firebase from UITableViewCell using Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612987/how-can-i-delete-a-specific-child-node-in-firebase-from-uitableviewcell-using-sw)

Comment: Please see my answer to [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876616/how-to-check-for-value-in-firebase-that-is-held-under-a-autoid-child?noredirect=1#comment68990882_40876616). It's a different question but the answer provides a design pattern that applies to your question. And... on that note, if you are observing the node in firebase for deleting, then you don't even need to remove it from your array. Once you know which node to delete, deleting that will notify your app, which will re-load the array and update your tableView accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to solve this problem is in your delete action, delete the object from Firebase. Do not alter the tableview from here.

Then in your data listener, check when the data comes back as deleted(or NULL), then remove it from the tableview datasource array and update the tableview.