# How do I retrieve the unique ID in swift to delete it(Firebase)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How would I be able to access the unique ID in swift for Firebase? I have tried almost everything this forum has, I'm trying to delete that certain node within a table cell in swift:

[image]

I tried creating a reference to from the Users email, and retrieving the IDs in a dictionary, however when I try to reference it from "indexPath", it returns the ID.

I went as far as trying an Array with a type int, string, any; and those yell at me.

I have included some sample code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        var currentEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email as String?

        if(editingStyle == .delete) {
            let ref = Database.database().reference()

            ref.child(currentEmail!).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

                if !snapshot.exists() {return} //may want to add better error handling here.

                let info = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

                let reff = info.index(ofAccessibilityElement: indexPath)

                print("info keys are:", reff)
            })
        }
```

Comment: Please give more info: what did you try, what didn't work?

Comment: im sorry, im a bit new to this stack overflow thing, i tried creating a reference to from the Users email, and retirving the IDs in a dictionary, however when i try to reference it from "indexPath" it gives me the ID... i went as far as trying an Array with a type int, string, any. and those yell at me...

Comment: No worries, I recommend you read [ask] first. It's also better to add extra info in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: i have updated the questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try snapshot.key? Example:

> self.uid = snapshot.key

Comment: you can try by print(snapshot.key)

Comment: it does the same thing like value, my question is how do I get it down to the ID part...?

Comment: if snapshot.key is the Email, then snapshot.value will be the UID, can u try 
print(snapshot.value) ? what do u get from that?

Comment: Optional("myEmail@domaincom")
{
    "-LtSHLRN2VsdJYmMz4A5" =     {
        message = "This is a test";
        teamName = test1;
    };            my end goal is to reach the "-LtSHLRN2VsdJYmMz4A5" so i can delete that part.. if that makes since?

Comment: sorry to ask this agin, but can i have the value of the snapshot.key? 
print(snapshot.key)

Comment: sure its : nice@nicecom

Comment: can u change the .observe(.value , the .value to .childadded ? and then print(snapshot.key) ?

Comment: -LtSHLRN2VsdJYmMz4A5
-LtSHUACuTJdn0r6YbvA
-LtSIAqMlENcoGXHpJx7      how would delete one of them? determined by indexPath.row

Comment: yes, you can delete the specific UID by inderPath.row.

Comment: it helped a lot! but how do i store it in a array though

Comment: because it gives me a warning when i try to place it as a NSArray -----Cast from 'String' to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fails

Comment: cause its not an array, u try cast it to [String:Anyobject]

Comment: then how would i be able to access the index of it so i can delete it from the database?

Comment: You can refer back to this link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612987/how-can-i-delete-a-specific-child-node-in-firebase-from-uitableviewcell-using-sw

if my answer is correct, Please do help give it a green tick. =)

Answer (score 0):

The email address of a user will contain a `.` character, which is not allowed in a key in Firebase. So that is probably the error message you get on `ref.child(currentEmail!)` (in the future, include the exact error message in your question please).

In your database, you have used the email address minus the `.` as the email address: `nice@nicecom`, which is probably the email address `nice@nice.com`.

So you'll also need to strip the `.` from `currentEmail` before passing it to the database.

So something like:

```
currentEmail = currentEmail!.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")
```

Comment: i already have that in there when the views load that's why it doesn't have the "." for the child, but im trying to get "LtSIAqMlENcoGXHpJx7" so i can delete that node(Also i really appreciate the help)

Comment: for instance, when i call the values or keys it gives me all of the nodes and the info in it, im trying to get one ID with pertaining to the indexPath.row for the table

Comment: What the error message you get ("and those yell at me")?

Comment: when i convert the NSDictonary to a NSArray. it crashes the code because it can't find anything data for it